# Intersection of infinitely many sets being none of them

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In my analysis class it came up that

$\bigcap_{q\in \mathbb{N}}[0,1/q] = \{0\}$

He was easily able to prove that this was so with a proof by contradiction since for any number greater than zero there is a $1/q$ less than that number.

However, we can also say that for the intersection of two sets when one is a subset of the other is going to be the set that is the subset of the others.

We can also say that for every two intervals of the form $[0,1/q]$, one of them is a subset of the other.

These two things together seem to imply that $\bigcap_{q\in \mathbb{N}}[0,1/q]$ must be contained in the set $\{[0,1/q],q \in \mathbb{N}\}$ which $\{0\}$ certainly is not.

Why is the conclusion false and not creating a contradiction.

Comment: How do you say "must be contained in the set..." and the nlist a set of natural numbers. What do you mean by $\{q\in \mathbb N\mid [0,1/q]\}$? Usually, we write a set as $\{q\in A\mid P(q)\}$ where $P(q)$ is a *predicate.* But $[0,1/q]$ is not a predicate.

Comment: Note that although any 2 of the intervals have the property you mention, there is no single interval $[0,1/q]$ contained in all of the intervals $[0,1/q']$. For any such interval there is a strictly smaller interval.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you for pointing out my mistake, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of how infinite collections behave very differently from finite ones.

You can show that if a *finite* collection of sets has the property that each is a subset or a superset of any other, then the intersection of the sets in that collection is one of the sets in that collection. But that says nothing about the infinite case.

Let me take a simpler example, with the same underlying logic. Any finite set of reals has a least element, but the set of positive reals has no least element.

The moral: when you want to prove something about infinite sets, it's not enough to just prove it for finite sets. Infinite sets have properties which finite sets don't.

Comment: The example is a makes a good parallel and it helps to see it in that light. But when do you know if you can apply the same logic to infinite sets as you can to finite sets?

Comment: @rphax: you need to construct a new intuition about infinite sets.  They are *very* different from finite sets.  The way we deal with infinite sets was constructed to preserve certain properties from finite sets, but some of the properties we are used to are inconsistent.  The mathematical community had to decide which  were the most important,  so you need to get a new intuition.